# PHP:confusing about keeping state with hidden filed

Tags: php, html

I would like to update the choice of poll to update every time that I've submitted.
but It seemed not working. Can anyone advice me about keeping state with hidden field?
and how to clear all the content in current page to display the poll result table?

```
<?php

if ($_POST['choice']==0)
    $a_count = $_POST['a_count']+1;
if ($_POST['choice']==1)
    $b_count = $_POST['b_count']+1;
if ($_POST['choice']==2)
    $c_count = $_POST['c_count']+1;
if ($_POST['choice']==3)
    $d_count = $_POST['d_count']+1;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <table align="center">
        <tr><td>Please select</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="0">aaaa</td></tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="a_count" value="<?php print $a_count ?>">
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">bbbb</td></tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="b_count" value="<?php print $b_count ?>">
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="2">cccc</td></tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="c_count" value="<?php print $c_count ?>">
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="3">dddd</td></tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="d_count" value="<?php print $d_count ?>">
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr align="center"><th>Member Name</th><th>Vote</th></tr>
        <tr><td>aaaa</td><td><?php echo"$a_count";?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>bbbb</td><td><?php echo"$b_count";?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>cccc</td><td><?php echo"$c_count";?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>dddd</td><td><?php echo"$d_count";?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to store your poll results in a database. PHP variables are cleared after every server request.

Comment: What are you actually asking for, if not a solution?  There are lots of ways to maintain state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you submitted looks like it should keep the user's selection/state during their active session (as long as they do not leave that page) - but as soon as they leave it's lost. Also, their "vote" cannot be shared between any other users.

To keep the user's state, explore the use of PHP sessions or storing results in a file/database.

To share the user's vote(s) with other users, explore the use of files or a database.

To show the results table without the form, after the user has "cast their vote", you can do one of two things. You could put an if-statement around the form to check if an answer has already been selected - if so, don't display the form. The other way would be to have the results-table on a separate page that doesn't have the form (just have the form POST to the separate page, or have the page with the form redirect to the separate page).

Comment: Thanks for your answer newfurnitury. I tried to update the vote score every time I submitted, but When I summitted choice 3 for 3 times. The score shown 3 then, submitted another choice the score for the choice 3 is gone. Could you explain me how to fix this.

Comment: That one's easy to do. In your PHP, you should pre-define the `$a_count`, `$b_count`, etc variables based on their POST values, and then increment them. For instance, try: `$a_count = $_POST['a_count'] + (($_POST['choice'] == 0) ? 1 : 0);`. This will set `$a_count` to the current value, and if the "choice" was A, it will increment it by one. You can do this for each count-variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the database to store values?? And you can put the table that you are using for the input in an if condition so that it does not render when the form is submitted. Hope this helps!